# Sinatra not sending JSON to outside request

Tags: jquery, json, sinatra

I'm having some problems requesting a JSON from my small Sinatra app. Actually the problem only occurs when the page that I use to make the request is outside of the project. My jQuery is basically this:

```
function number(){
          var aux = 0;
          $.getJSON('http://localhost:4567/test', function(data){
              //Display Code
          });

      }
```

Like I said before, when this is placed in a view(erb file) that is part of my project, it works perfectly. The problem only occurs when making an outside request.

Answer (score 0):

It was a same-origin problem, solved just adding the permission to any page to make the request.